# Is there a specific pattern for logging with multiple guarda but with single api

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, postman

In a Laravel project,there are five users with different 5 guards,

I want to create a single function for login for all these users.

Is there any a specific way to do that instead of if ..elseif..else ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is functionality or structurally different about these 5 user types?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have five guards, so you have five different models also

so if you want to perform login with single controller's function then you have to pass user type of for filtration.

Because when you pass credentials to login function with multiple guards, then you have to specify user type for filtration of models because after that we can identify on which model we have to check credentials

And if you have more guards then you can use Switch case also

Maybe it will helpful

Comment: Actually, I develod the function as your answer.

Comment: Ok, did it work as per your aspect?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, thanks for your time

Comment: ok, then could you please approve it?